# Cannot find the file with python

Tags: python

When I run the command in the terminal everything is fine, however, in my python program, I got the error

> File not found: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"ls", "-R","/home/mathieu/nas/Music/","|","grep",".mp3","|","sed","-n", "{0}".format(argument)'

Here is the code which is not working:

```py
for x in range(mp3count):
     argument = str(x + 1) + 'p'
     fichier = subprocess.check_output([r'"ls", "-R","/home/mathieu/nas/Music/","|","grep",".mp3","|","sed","-n", "{0}".format(argument)'])
```

Comment: Why are there quotes in the list literal? `r' ... '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: example of absolute path for "ls" is /usr/bin/ls

It depends on your system

---

You need to type the absolute path of the "ls" command.
To find out the location of "ls" binary in your system. It can usually be found by using the "where" or "which" command like this:

```
where ls
```

or

```
which ls
```

Comment: It is what I am doing the path is absolute

Comment: @Math142 no, for the "ls" it is not. your path is only absolute for the folder. you need to make your "ls" absolute. Like "/usr/bin/ls" for example.

Comment: oh ok I understand

Answer (score 0):

probably it is because of the main.py ( start point of your app) location ls is running from where your python start point location
try
'''
eubprocess.check_output('ls')
'''
check the result to see where are you
and if your files are there